# Iam unable to get the html inside the title tag of bootstrap tool tip rendered as html, instead it is displayed as tags,

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse offset footer-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <div class="nav navbar-nav menu_nav ml-auto branches justify-content-center">
                            <a  href="#" class="khi" style="color:#dd101d;" class="tooltip bs-tooltip-top" title="<div>Tooltip Text</div>"> <div class="arrow"></div>
                                Karachi


                            </a>



                            <a  href="#" class="isl" style="color:#dd101d;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="<em>Tooltip</em> <u>with</u> <b>HTML</b>">Islamabad

                            </a>
                            <a href="#"  class="lhr" style="color:#dd101d;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Lahore Branch">Lahore

                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="mul" style="color:#dd101d;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Multan Branch">Multan 

                            </a>
                            <a  href="#" class="guj" style="color:#dd101d;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Gujranwala Branch">Gujranwala

                            </a>
                            <a href="#"  class="fsl" style="color:#dd101d;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Faisalabad Branch">Faisalabad

                            </a>
                            <a href="#"  class="ryk" style="color:#dd101d;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Rahimyarkhan Branch">Rahimyarkhan

                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="suk"  style="color:#dd101d;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Sukkur Branch">Sukkur

                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="hyd"  style="color:#dd101d;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Peshawar Branch">Peshawar

                            </a>
                            <a  href="#"  class="khi"  style="color:#dd101d;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" titlle="Hyderabad Branch">Hyderabad

                            </a>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

$(document).ready(function(){
               `$('.khi').tooltip();
                $('.isl').tooltip();
                $('.lhr').tooltip();
                $('.guj').tooltip();
                $('.ryk').tooltip();
                $('.hyd').tooltip();
                $('.suk').tooltip();
                $('.mul').tooltip();
                $('.fsl').tooltip();
    });

Comment: your markup is invalid near the start. You cannot open and close tags in the order that you do above and you cannot have HTML tags inside the `title` of another tag